# Not quite sure how .htaccess/.htpasswd authentication saves passwords

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

That's right.
I have an .htaccess file in a folder called admin, inside of my web directory. It contains this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /storage/ssd2/048/1839048/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I also have an .htpasswd file above my web directory, so visitors can't see it:

```
test:dGRkPurkuWmW2
```

Everything works fine, but i can't figure out how this method of authentication can save passwords. When i accessed the protected directory for the first time, it asked me for the user and password, but now that i'm refreshing the page it doesen't ask me anymore. I cleared cookies in my browser and restarted it, but the password is still saved. Anyone knows how this works?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Protocol

Comment: Is there a way to make it ask me for the login every time i access the page? (sry im kind of a noob at this)

Comment: You can force the browser to reauthenticate by sending the appropiate 401 header with every request. But I don't see why anybody would want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing cookies didn't help because the password is saved by the browser, but it's not in a *cookie* defined in *HTTP State Management Mechanism* ([RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)), like for example session IDs:

> == Server -> User Agent ==
>
> ```
>    Set-Cookie: SID=31d4d96e407aad42; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
>    Set-Cookie: lang=en-US; Path=/; Domain=example.com
> ```
>
> == User Agent -> Server ==
>
> ```
>    Cookie: SID=31d4d96e407aad42; lang=en-US
> ```

This kind of SIDs are used by more sophisticated authentication mechanisms that only checks once for a password and then trusts this user is authenticated based on only the presence of the cookie.

Instead, `AuthType Basic` uses `Authorization = credentials` header from *HTTP Authentication* ([RFC 7235, 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2)). This is a very basic authentication mechanism that sends the credentials on every HTTP request, in format: `credentials = auth-scheme [ 1*SP ( token68 / #auth-param ) ]`.

The browser keeps sending it until it gets new [`401 Unauthorized`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) status code in the HTTP response:

> If a request is authenticated and a realm specified, the same credentials are presumed to be valid for all other requests within this realm (assuming that the authentication scheme itself does not require otherwise, such as credentials that vary according to a challenge value or using synchronized clocks).

One way to force this without actively configuring something to send `401` is to cause the user to use an URL with other username and password in it, i.e. `http://forcelog:out@example.com/` (link or JS).

Browsers usually clears basic authentication information on restart. Additionally (not complete list):

- Chrome & Chromium clears it when you restart with `chrome://restart` in address bar.
- Firefox clears it when you clear history: Active Logins.
- Internet Explorer allows ActiveX control to clear it.